# Centering an absolute element until ranges without js

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have a dropdown which has title and content. Content should be centered is relatively to title, **if only** there is empty place for it. If there is no empty place, content should cuddle to the parent's border.

I've prepared a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/a62vcecs/1/). This demo has a follow significant code:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.dropdown_content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown_button"></div>
    <div class="dropdown_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now `.dropdown_content` floats beyond the borders when second `input[type="range"]` has a small value. This behaviour is bad. I want in this case `.dropdown_content` to cuddle to the left border.

**Desired result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed the absolute positioning see: https://jsfiddle.net/v9amen50/.

That seems to work.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown_button {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown_content {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown_content::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 24px;
  content: "";
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="range" name="title" min="1" max="100" , value="5">
</div>

<div class="block">
  <input type="range" name="position" min="0" max="500" , value="0">
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown_button"></div>
    <div class="dropdown_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```